# Conversion from EBCDIC to UTF8 in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, utf-8, iconv, ebcdic

I have imported with Perl a table from our database AS/400 DB2.

The problem is that the string are encoded in EBCDIC Latin-1 (italian language).

How can I convert the resulting file to plain utf-8 in Linux bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple with `iconv`.

```
iconv -f ISO8859-1   -t "UTF-8" result.csv -o new_result.csv
```

ISO8859-1 is the Latin-1 encoding format. For a list of encodings, refer t this table from official IBM documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.nls/doc/nlsgdrf/iconv.htm%23d722e3a267mela

Note that the conversion may leave non valid UTF-8 characters from EBCDIC. An example are NULL characters in the strings. To avoid this, use an HEX editor and replace hex values from 00 to 20 (space character).

Answer (score 5):

Start with

```
iconv -f EBCDIC-IT -t utf-8 <filename>
```

then check the output, and if it isn't exactly correct, check `man iconv` and the available encodings listed by `iconv -l`.

(Note that "EBCDIC Latin-1" is somewhat strange. "Latin-1" indicates ISO-8859-1, while "EBCDIC" is something else entirely. Try `file <filename>` to get an educated guess by the computer as to what encoding you are actually looking at.)

Answer (score 2):

I had good luck with the following line:

```
iconv -f IBM037 -t utf-8 input_ebcdic.txt -o output.txt
```