# External Table Oracle using EBCDIC file in binary format - Error KUP-03003

Tags: oracle, decimal, sql-loader, external-tables, ebcdic

**My environment: Oracle 12.2 on Red Hat version 7 ( database characterset AL32UTF8 )**

I am having a huge issue dealing with an external table which points to a file in EBCDIC format coming from an AS400 system. I could figure out finally the length of the record and the position of each field. My problem now is that some fields are packets in COMP-3 format and I am struggling with the error KUP-03003.

Let me show you what happens. I load them all as varchar2 columns because later on I have a process to transform each field to the right data type format for the final staging table that is going to be used in the batch process.

1.This is the external table definition

```
DROP TABLE CPL_HIST.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP purge;

CREATE TABLE CPL_HIST.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP
( 
  LMZMDT         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  LMORNB         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  LMH6NE         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  LMG9VA         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  LMHAVA         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  LMA8PS         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMALEU         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMHBVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMHCVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMIHNE         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMHDVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMA9PS         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMBAPS         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMO1TT         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMAMEU         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMHEVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMFINB         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMECNE         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMYXNF         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMD5EU         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMSTVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMSUVA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMQECE         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMU4VA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMU5VA         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMDVDT         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMDWDT         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMAJTM         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMLPXT         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMLQXT         VARCHAR2(4000 char),
  LMNUST         VARCHAR2(4000 char)
  )
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
( TYPE oracle_loader
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY DIR_CPL_EXT
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
 RECORDS FIXED 176 CHARACTERSET WE8EBCDIC500
 BADFILE 'EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP.bad'
 DISCARDFILE 'EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP.dsc'
 LOGFILE 'EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP.log'
 READSIZE 1048576 
 FIELDS LTRIM
 MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
 REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
 (
LMZMDT (1:3)          CHAR                  ,    
LMORNB (4:9)          DECIMAL(10,0)          ,
LMH6NE (10:11)        DECIMAL(2,0)          ,
LMG9VA (12:18)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMHAVA (19:25)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMA8PS (26:28)        DECIMAL(3,2)          ,
LMALEU (29:38)        CHAR                  ,
LMHBVA (39:45)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMHCVA (46:52)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMIHNE (53:53)        DECIMAL(1,0)          ,
LMHDVA (54:60)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMA9PS (61:63)        DECIMAL(3,2)          ,
LMBAPS (64:66)        DECIMAL(3,2)          ,
LMO1TT (67:76)        CHAR                  , 
LMAMEU (77:86)        CHAR                  ,
LMHEVA (87:93)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMFINB (94:95)        DECIMAL(2,0)          ,
LMECNE (96:100)       DECIMAL(5,0)          ,
LMYXNF (101:105)      DECIMAL(5,0)          ,
LMD5EU (106:115)      CHAR                  ,
LMSTVA (116:122)      DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMSUVA (123:129)      DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMQECE (130:131)      CHAR                  ,
LMU4VA (132:134)      DECIMAL(3,3)          ,
LMU5VA (135:142)      DECIMAL(8,2)          ,
LMDVDT (143:146)      DECIMAL(4,0)          ,
LMDWDT (147:150)      DECIMAL(4,0)          ,
LMAJTM (151:154)      DECIMAL(4,0)          ,
LMLPXT (155:164)      CHAR                  ,
LMLQXT (165:174)      CHAR                  ,
LMNUST (175:176)      CHAR
 )
 )
 location
 (
 'RPLMREP.bin'
 )
 ) 
 REJECT LIMIT 0
 /
```

2.Then I create the table

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Sep 11 13:13:03 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production


Table dropped.


Table created.
```

What you see above is the definition I have of the same table in a SAS program that treats the same file without issues. Now, if I try to read the first field in the table, I got an error for the last field in the table.

```
SQL> select LMZMDT from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10 ;
select LMZMDT from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-03003: absolute end(154) - start(151) != fieldlength (3) for field LMAJTM
```

Obviously, if I put all the fields to CHAR, then all the COMP-3 decimal packets are not loaded. What I did test was to verify which fields were the problem by putting all the fields in char, then starting to change one by one. What I can't understand is why the lengths are not matching with the specification for those fields and the position they occupy.

Let me show you an example. I create the table only with the right format in the first 4 fields

```
LMZMDT (1:3)          CHAR                  ,    
LMORNB (4:9)          DECIMAL(10,0)          ,
LMH6NE (10:11)        DECIMAL(2,0)          ,
LMG9VA (12:18)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMHAVA (19:25)        DECIMAL(7,2)          ,
LMA8PS (26:28)        CHAR                 ,
LMALEU (29:38)        CHAR                 ,
LMHBVA (39:45)        CHAR                 ,
LMHCVA (46:52)        CHAR                 ,
LMIHNE (53:53)        CHAR                 ,
LMHDVA (54:60)        CHAR                 ,
LMA9PS (61:63)        CHAR                 ,
LMBAPS (64:66)        CHAR                 ,
LMO1TT (67:76)        CHAR                 , 
LMAMEU (77:86)        CHAR                 ,
LMHEVA (87:93)        CHAR                 ,
LMFINB (94:95)        CHAR                 ,
LMECNE (96:100)       CHAR                 ,
LMYXNF (101:105)      CHAR                 ,
LMD5EU (106:115)      CHAR                 ,
LMSTVA (116:122)      CHAR                 ,
LMSUVA (123:129)      CHAR                 ,
LMQECE (130:131)      CHAR                 ,
LMU4VA (132:134)      CHAR                 ,
LMU5VA (135:142)      CHAR                 ,
LMDVDT (143:146)      CHAR                 ,
LMDWDT (147:150)      CHAR                 ,
LMAJTM (151:154)      CHAR                 ,
LMLPXT (155:164)      CHAR                 ,
LMLQXT (165:174)      CHAR                 ,
LMNUST (175:176)      CHAR
```

After creating the table with this format, I got

```
SQL> select LMZMDT from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10 ;
select LMZMDT from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-03003: absolute end(25) - start(19) != fieldlength (4) for field LMHAVA
```

However, If I change the definition to ( only the four first fields )

```
LMZMDT (1:3)          CHAR                  ,    
LMORNB (4:9)          DECIMAL(10,0)          ,
LMH6NE (10:11)        DECIMAL(2,0)          ,
LMG9VA (12:18)        DECIMAL(10,2)          ,
LMHAVA (19:25)        DECIMAL(10,2)          ,
```

Then the query works until the fourth field.

```
SQL>  select LMZMDT from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10 ;

LMZMDT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB
AKB

9 rows selected.

SQL> select LMORNB from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10 ;

LMORNB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1020019630
1020083310
1020087030
1020120440
1020121681
1020127470
1020147350
1020169610
1020223080

SQL> select LMHAVA from cpl_hist.EXT_L027_AS_RPLMREP a where a.LMZMDT is not null and rownum < 10 ;

LMHAVA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00

9 rows selected.
```

As I have no way to read the file to see whether the positions are matching the specification. I have some questions:

- Why if I put just `DECIMAL` without specifying precision or scale, the load does not work and I got the same KUP error ?
- Do I have to do this for each field ? I am struggling because there are tables with more than 100 columns.
- Is there a better way to read packet decimal fields from external tables with EBCDIC codepage ? Or any utility that can convert this file to ascii that I can check the positions.
- Why the supposed length that works in other systems is not valid for the decimal data type ?
- I guess I am using the right characterset for the file ( WE8EBCDIC500 ). Do I ?

Hope you can help
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that packed decimals in ECBDIC normally include caharacters like '0C' that cannot be loaded into a deciaml column in the table.

The only suggetion is to first convert your EBCDIC file to UTF-8 format.

Look at this:

[Conversion from EBCDIC to UTF8 in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496008/conversion-from-ebcdic-to-utf8-in-linux)

This is the list of EBCDIC codes supported by iconv:

IBM-037          Europe
IBM-1025         Cyrillic
IBM-1026         Latin 5 (Turkey)
IBM-1027         Japan Latin
IBM-1047         Open Systems
IBM-1112         Baltic
IBM-1122         Estonia
IBM-1140         Finland, Sweden
IBM-1141         Austria, Germany
IBM-1142         Denmark, Norway
IBM-1143         USA
IBM-1144         Italy
IBM-1145         Spain, spanish-speaking Latin America
IBM-1146         UK
IBM-1147         France
IBM-1148         Belgium, Switzerland
IBM-1149         Iceland
IBM-1388         China
IBM-273          Germany
IBM-274          Belgium
IBM-277          Denmark - Norway
IBM-278          Sweden - Finland
IBM-280          Italy
IBM-284          Spain - Latin America
IBM-285          UK
IBM-290          Japanese Katakana
IBM-297          France
IBM-424          Israel
IBM-500          International
IBM-838          Thai
IBM-871          Iceland
IBM-875          Greek
IBM-924          IBM500/IBM1047 with euro
IBM-930          Japanese Katakana/Kanji multibyte
IBM-933          Korea
IBM-935          China
IBM-937          Taiwan
IBM-939          Japan Extended
IBM-970          Latin 2
IBM-971          Iceland
IBM-975          Greece

try them.

or else the oracle funcion:

CONVERT( string1, char_set_to [, char_set_from] )
for instance:
convert( variable, 'UTF8', 'WE8EBCDIC500')

If you are in trouble with iconv simply create the external table with one single field and then select the convert(...) of any row into one more table or use a pl/sql procedure to populate a new table splitting the converted rows.

Comment: I tried the conversion article and it does not work in my case. Any of the options described there.

Comment: what do I have to use convert in this scenario ? I am specifying characterset WE8EBCDIC500 in the external table, that should do the conversion by itself without invoking any function, isn't it ?

Comment: Here are some more tips.