# Python - read EBCIDIC encoded .dat file into a pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shell, encoding, db2

I have a .dat file exported from a mainframe system. It is EBCIDIC encoded(cp037). I would like to load the contents into a pandas or spark dataframe.

I tried using "`iconv`" to convert the file to ascii, it does not support conversion from cp037.  "`iconv -l`" does not list cp037.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd guess that `pandas`' functions `read_*` accept an (optional) `encoding='cp037'` parameter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496008/conversion-from-ebcdic-to-utf8-in-linux . Note on my system I have `IBM037` and `CP037`